# what solution for program not working correctly

Tags: c++

My program has a problem. My code can run but something is causing it to stop working. I have checked the program many times but i can't see the problem. Thanks to anyone that helps me. It's really appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double getdiscount(int customer_city, double gal_last)

{
     getdiscount(customer_city, gal_last);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int customer_city ;
    double gal_last, gal_bought, price_per_gal, discount, tot_cost;

    cout << " The number of gallon being purchased in gal: " << endl;
    cin >> gal_bought;

    cout << " The price per gallon you bought : "<<"RM";
    cin >> price_per_gal;

    cout<<" Enter customer city : "<<endl;
    cin>>customer_city;

    cout<<" Number of gallons of oil used last year : " <<endl;
    cin>>gal_last;

    switch (customer_city)

    {
    case 1:
        (customer_city == 1);
        if (gal_last>=1000)
            discount = 0.9;
        else
            discount = 1;
        break;

    case 2:
        (customer_city == 2);
        (gal_last >=1200);
        discount = 0.9;
        break;

    default:
        if (gal_last >=1500)
            discount = 0.9;

        cout<< " Discount rate is : "<<discount<<endl;
    }

     tot_cost = gal_bought* (price_per_gal*getdiscount(customer_city, gal_last) );

    cout<< " The total cost : "<<tot_cost<<endl;

    return 0;
} //end main function
```

Comment: Debug and see at which line it fails]

Comment: Doesn't that getdiscount function just enter a recursive infinite loop?

Comment: Look at your `getdiscount()` function. The only work it does is to recursively call itself. Please finish writing your program and then come back.

Comment: What kind of error do you get during runtime? It would be a lot easier to answer this question if you give us your log output to see where the error occurs

Answer (score 4):

This is recursively calling itself...

```
double getdiscount(int customer_city, double gal_last)

{
     getdiscount(customer_city, gal_last);
    return 0;
}
```

Till you get a stackoverflow...

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. But it's not really the *right* answer. Give a man a fish...

Comment: @adelphus, in this case, it's pretty simple oversight, sometimes another pair of eyes just does the trick...